# Laravel 5.6 required_if checkbox is checked

Tags: laravel, forms, validation

In my form I validate fields using rules with a validation group called 'my-event'. One of my rules is if a checkbox is checked called 'other', then the text field 'other' needs to be filled in. There are 8 checkboxes in total.

The name of the input is called `event-type`, and there is a checkbox with the value `other`.

The rule that I have written for this validation is:

```
"my-event.event-type": "required",

"my-event.event-type-other":  "required_if:my-event.event-type,other",
```

However I am not getting any validation issues when I check the checkbox "other"  and do not fill out the text field. I have dumped out the request and can see that the "other" checkbox is checked:

```
"event-type" => array:6 [▼
          0 => "casual"
          1 => "free"
          2 => "other"
        ]
```

Is there anything I should be focusing on when trying to resolve this issue?

Comment: I think the value you should use is: 2, not other. You should check on the key, not the value. Haven't tested it

Comment: @Ruub however, say only 'other' is checked, the request looks like this ` 0 => "other"` so it's just the array index from the user input. The key for the checkbox is 'other' and the value is 'Other'.